# Tkinter doesn't see file in project directory even though os.path.exists() does

Tags: python, visual-studio, image, file, tkinter

I have PNG icons for my buttons in Tkinter, and the function picking the right one looks like this:

```
def square_pic(b: chess.board, i: int, j: int):
    square = b.board_state[i][j]
    color = (i + j) %2
    if square.s_piece !=0:
        return "{0}_{1}_{2}.PNG".format(square.s_piece, square.s_color, color)
    else:
        return "0_{0}".format(color)
```

The code that creates a button with an icon looks like this:

```
            photo = square_pic(b, i, j)
            print(os.path.exists(photo))
            t=Button(root, height=40, width=40, image=photo)
            t.grid(row=7-i,column=j, sticky=W)
```

It prints "True" to the console yet throws an exception "image "4_0_1.PNG" doesn't exist". Why does tkinter not see the image? I'm using Python 3.9 and Visual Studio 2022, if it matters.

Comment: Try using `photo = PhotoImage(file=photo)`

Comment: As JonSG shows, you need to use a `PhotoImage` to create an image in `tkinter`. Right now, you're giving your `Button` the _path_ to the image, not the actual image itself.